# 403 Error when attempting to access a Webservice

Tags: asp.net, rest, soapui

I get the following response when I try to access a REST web service

date: Mon, 09 Mar 2020 15:27:42 GMT 
 server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0 
 status: 403 
 x-powered-by: ASP.NET

I have configured SOAPUI to use the security certs I created by adding them as Keystores and preferences within Rest API. However I keep getting this error when trying to contact the webservice !

error on Soap when attempting to connect to the Swagger

*unable to read location `https://iecwcbitsvr130/swagger/v1/swagger.json` due to a SSL configuration error. It is possible that the server SSL certificate is invalid, self-signed, or has an untrusted Certificate Authority.*

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give a specific answer without more information. However, my guess would be that the two errors are somewhat unrelated.

A `403` response indicates that you are *unauthorised* but not *unauthenticated* (see [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.3)). At a high level this means that the server trusts you are who you say you are but has decided that you're not allowed to access the resource or perform the action you have requested. Imagine you send a request to the StackOverflow API to delete **a different** user's question. You provide your credentials in the request. The API would respond with `403` to indicate that it has accepted your credentials but you don't have permission to delete **a different** user's question.

For the second issue I'd recommend that you try and access that address in a browser. If you click on the padlock somewhere at the top (it depends on what browser you are using) you should be able to see information about the certificate being used. In general certificate errors are the fault of the service you are accessing but you'll need to see why it is being refused to know for sure.